# Why is Visual Studio Color Coding only the First Line of an XML File

Tags: xml, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 17.6.2.  When I open an XML file, only the first line of the file is properly color coded.  The rest of the XML file is color coded all the same: black.  Where is the setting for color coding XML?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio go to:
**tools** > **options** > **environment** > **Fonts and color**

On **fonts and color** tab:

Set **Show setting for** = text editor
under **display items** list, there are XML attributes at the end of the list.

Select the desired attribute and change its properties, on the right.

The available properties to update, for each item are:

- Item foreground (color)
- Item background (color)
- Bold (check)

Comment: There are only two: XML Doc Comment, which I set to Green, and XML Doc Tag, which I set to Magenta.  This resulted is no change to the XML; it remained black font against a white background (as in the picture).

Answer (score 0):

<sub>[Just realized I wrote this answer about vscode rather than visual studio.  There's a good chance the same reason (line too long) applies, so I'll leave this here.  I do not use visual studio.]</sub>

Starting at line 2, your XML is all on a single line, which is too long for color coding.

1. Select the whole file.
2. Issue command, "Format Document".

The XML will now be color coded.